# Include several google fonts in a WordPress theme and allow user to select them

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-font-api, google-webfonts

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I need to include several Google fonts (may be nearly 10) in the theme and it's up to the user to select which font is used for Headings, Paragraphs and other elements.

I've an option page in the back-end and there the user is able to select them.

So, my question is how to enqueue all those fonts in the theme. Enqueuing all the fonts at once as the normal enqueuing way will seriously cause performance issues and will slow down the site.

So, should I use a condition like this in the functions page where enguing script goes ?

> (The following code is not a real one.)

```
if($options['font'] == "Open-sans"){
    enque "open-sans"
}else if($options['font'] == "some-font1"){
    enque "some-font"
}else if(){
......................
......................
......................
}
```

Or is there any other way ?

Comment: Simply `if($options['font']) enqueue($options['font']); else enqueue($default);`?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know  :)